# My database query keeps setting all columns to the same value in MySQL

Tags: php, database, insert, kohana

Here is my update method for Kohana 3.

```
public function update($type, $id, $updates) {
        $info = $this->getInfo($type);
        $dbTable = $info['table'];

        $updatesKeysToValues = array();

        var_dump($updates);

        foreach($updates as $key => $value) {
            // if the value is null or the key isnt set for this, don't update!
            if ($value === null OR ! isset($info['columnsToUpdateData'][$key])) continue;
            $updatesKeyToValues[] = "`$key` = :$key";

        }

        $updatesKeyToValues = implode(', ', $updatesKeyToValues);

        $query = 'UPDATE `' . $dbTable . '` SET ' . $updatesKeyToValues . ' WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1' ; 

        echo $query;

        $dbQuery = DB::query(Database::UPDATE, $query);

        foreach($updates as $key => $value) {
                echo "$key === $value\n<br>";
                $dbQuery->bind(':' . $key, $value);
         }

        $success = $dbQuery->bind(':id', $id)    
                        ->execute();    

        var_dump($success);

    }
```

During every `var_dump()` and `echo` the data is fine. There is nothing to suggest why this is happening.

Essentially what I am doing is getting the data for this table from the config, building a query string with named params, looping and defining the named params and then executing. Instead of working, I end up with all fields the same (seems to be whatever was the last array value).

I can't seem to figure it out, can you? Many thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

I just had a thought, are underscores valid in param names in a query?

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Here is the output of the `echo $query`

```
UPDATE `personnel` SET `first_name` = :first_name, `last_name` = :last_name, `email` = :email WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1
```

I also cooked up that method of binding multiple params to the query too. I've never done it in a loop before, but I assumed it would work. In Kohana 2.x, I'd always used `$bindings[] = 'tom@jones.com'` etc, but the new Kohana doesn't accept an array as far as I can tell.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Thanks everyone, I think it is being passed by reference. I got around it by setting it to `$updates[$key]`

Looks like I could of also used the `param()` method instead of bind. [View source](http://github.com/kohana/database/blob/master/classes/kohana/database/query.php#L113)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the bind function is using a reference the your $value

```
public function bind($param, & $var)
{
 // Bind a value to a variable
    $this->_parameters[$param] =& $var;
    return $this;
}
```

Something that seems to work in a test

```
$a = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5, "f"=>6);
$v = array();
$t = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($a as $key => $value)
{
    $t[] = $key;
    $v[] = &$t[$i];
    $i++;
}

print_r($v);
```

results are here:
http://www.antiyes.com/test/hmm.php

do you think the $key & $value in

```
$dbQuery->bind(':' . $key, $value);
```

are being passed by reference ?

below didnt work

---

this line

```
$updatesKeyToValues[] = "`$key` = :$key";
```

could you change it to:

```
$updatesKeyToValues[] = "`" . $key ."` = " . ":" . $key;
```

and see what happens?

Comment: Just tried that, and still no good. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Regarding pass by reference, perhaps! Good thought, let me check out the DB class's code now.

Comment: The database class files are here: http://github.com/kohana/database/tree/master/classes/kohana/

Comment: http://github.com/kohana/database/blob/master/classes/kohana/database/query.php line 122

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what data access layer you're using here, but I'm guessing this:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $value) {
    $dbQuery->bind(':' . $key, $value);
}
```

could be doing something really deceptive: taking the parameters by reference.

So what would happen would be that since `$value` is a real variable, the `bind()` function receives a reference to it and remembers that it's this *variable* — *not* the variable's current value — that it will bind to the given parameter. Then you go the next time round the `foreach` loop, and we've got the classic loop problem of C-like languages: you're not getting a new instance of `$key` and `$value`, you're actually changing the existing variables you already had, just like for the standard `for ($i= 0...` loop.

So, when it comes time to do the query, what's parameter `:a`? It's the current value of `$value`, the last one in the loop. What's parameter `:b`? The same. And so on.

I know some PHP parameterisation interfaces do this (mysqli, I think?), but in general receiving parameters by reference is IMO extremely likely to lead to unwanted behaviours like this, and I certainly consider it totally inappropriate for a parameter-binding interface like this.

ETA: just looked at query.php in the link you posted to John's comment. Yes. Sigh. It's taking parameters by reference. How awful.

Comment: I think you are right Bobince. I don't want to hack the system files of Kohana, so I'll investigate another way to do it. +1

Comment: Can I cancel a pass by reference, or do I need to implement an ugly hack, e.g. make a temporary variable for each loop that will always stay as is?

Comment: can you create temporary map/array? to hold the values?

Comment: Not tried that but the PHP manual says you can only pass variables and ‘new’​ed objects as references. How inconvenient. And yes, looks like mysqli does the same thing. At least in PDO this misfeature is optional (bindValue also exists to do it the expected way).

Comment: @alex Adding an unset($value) inside the end of that loop should do it.

Comment: I made an update and it worked. Thanks much for your comments and answers!

Comment: Ah, good hack bluej! (I didn't know PHP variable binding worked like that. Are you sure it's all right to `unset` a variable you've passed by reference to someone else though? OK, it would work in most scripting languages, but I can't find confirmation...)

Comment: @bobince It'll just remove $value from the symbol table, without affecting its value or the query's reference. Check out the static example in the docs: http://us2.php.net/unset

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the query-builder?

This is just a quick guess, as I haven't had enough time to play with the query-builder myself.

```
$query = DB::update();
$query->set($updates);
// etc
```

Check out the source and I'm sure you could figure out how the query-builder works :)